# Cannot update PS1 to change terminal prompt

Tags: linux, terminal, prompt

I am using konsole

```
echo $PS1
```

gives

> ${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_msg-}${_p9k__raw_msg::=}%}${(e)_p9k_t[7]}${_p9k__1-${${:-${_p9k__d::=0}${_p9k__rprompt::=${_p9k__1r-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=8}}${_p9k__n:=${${}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rstatus+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{000}%F{002}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{000}%F{002} %b%K{000}%F{002}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{000}%F{002} }${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=000}}+}}${${:-"${${(%):-%j}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=""}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${*p9k__n::=12}}${*p9k**}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rbackground_jobs+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{000}%F{006}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{000}%F{006} %b%K{000}%F{006}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{000}%F{006} }${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=000}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:##}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n:}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{000}%F{003}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{000}%F{003} %b%K{000}%F{003}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{000}%F{003} }${_p9k__i::=30}${_p9k__bg::=000}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#%}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=24}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{000}%F{001}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{000}%F{001} %b%K{000}%F{001}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{000}%F{001} }${_p9k__i::=30}${_p9k__bg::=000}}+}}}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*insert*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=OVERTYPE}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=28}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(003|003)}:+30}}${_p9k__n:=31}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${*p9k*}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{003}%F{000}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{003}%F{000} %b%K{003}%F{000}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{003}%F{000} }${_p9k__i::=38}${_p9k__bg::=003}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#vicmd0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=NORMAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{002}%F{000}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{002}%F{000} %b%K{002}%F{000}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{002}%F{000} }${_p9k__i::=38}${_p9k__bg::=002}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#(vicmd1|vivis?|vivli?)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=VISUAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NON}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{004}%F{000}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{004}%F{000} %b%K{004}%F{000}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{004}%F{000} }${_p9k__i::=38}${_p9k__bg::=004}}+}}}$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}${_p9k__lprompt::=${_p9k__1l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=40}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x007}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+42}}${_p9k__n:=43}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1los_icon+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%K{007}%F{030} ${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{007}}${_p9k__ss::=}${_p9k__sss::=%F{007}}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=007}}+}}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="%{d%}${:-"%B%F{255}"}${(Q)${:-"~"}}${:-"%b%K{030}%F{254}"}%{d%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=44}}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1ldir+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%K{030}%F{254} ${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{030}}${_p9k__ss::=}${_p9k__sss::=%F{030}}${_p9k__i::=2}${_p9k__bg::=030}}+}}${(e)_p9k__vcs}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}}}}+}${(e)_p9k_t[6]}${${_p9k__h::=72.}+}${${_p9k__d::=$((_p9k__m-_p9k__h))}+}${_p9k__lprompt/%{d%}*%{d%}/${_p9k__1ldir-${:-"%B%F{255}"}${(Q)${:-"~"}}${:-"%b%K{030}%F{254}"}}}${${_p9k__m::=$((_p9k__d+_p9k__h))}+}}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k__clm}+}

I have changed ~/.bashrc to include

```
PS1="\[\e[30m\]\u@\h \w \$ \[\e[m\]"
```

and run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

but if I echo $PS1 again I  get the original result

If I run

```
grep -RH "PS1=" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/ /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

I get the output

```
/home/jeff/.bashrc:             #PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
/home/jeff/.bashrc:             #PS1='\[\033[01;32m\][\u@\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;32m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
/home/jeff/.bashrc:             #PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
/home/jeff/.bashrc:             #PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
/home/jeff/.bashrc:PS1="\[\e[30m\]\u@\h \w \$ \[\e[m\]"
/etc/bash.bashrc:PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Something else is setting your `PS1`. Most probably `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. Please  [edit] your question and add the output of `grep -RH "PS1=" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/ /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`. Also tell us which Linux you are using, how you are using it (is it a remote machine? local? Do you login graphically? Over ssh?)

Comment: @terdon Question updated

Comment: Look at, but Do Not Post `bash -x ~/.bashrc`. Something (involved with `p9k`?) is setting `PS1` after you set it. Check the files you `source` or `.` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks all. I found the solution thanks to your help, I have a file .zshrc which contains the line: "source /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-prompt". Commenting out that line solves the problem